# nonlinear heat equation with decreasing "energy" function.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the nonlinear heat equation in smooth bounded domain $\Omega$ 
\begin{align*} u_t-\Delta u+f(u)&=0\\
u&=0 \ \text{on} \ \partial \Omega\\
u(0,x)&=g(x)
\end{align*}
where $f\in C^1$ denote $F$ by the primitive of $f$ such that $F(0)=0$.Assume that $u$ is smooth. 
Show that the function $E(u(t))$ defined as $$E(u)=\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2+\int_{\Omega}F(u)\;dx$$
is decreasing.

So following the hint, we have that $$\int_{\Omega}uu_t-u\Delta u +uf(u)\;dx=0\ \tag{1}$$
$$\int_\Omega u_t^2-u_t\Delta u+u_tf(u)\;dx=0 \tag{2}$$
Therefore, using integration by parts and the boundary value condition, we have $\int uu_t=0$ and $\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2+uf(u)=0$. Next to show that $E(u)$ is decreasing, taking the derivative would yield $|\nabla u|\Delta u+F(u)$. What to continue after having done all this (I m not sure all the calculation I did is correct)? Thanks for all the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that
$$\begin{aligned}
E(u)&=\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\nabla u\;dx+\int_\Omega F(u)\;dx\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega u\Delta u\;dx+\int_\Omega F(u)\;dx
\end{aligned}$$
and thus
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dt}E(u)&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega (u_t\Delta u+u\Delta u_t)\;dx+\int_\Omega F'(u)u_t\;dx\\\\
&=-\int_\Omega u_t\Delta u\;dx+\int_\Omega f(u)u_t\;dx
\end{aligned}$$
So, by $(2)$,
$$\frac{d}{dt}E(u)=-\int_\Omega u_t^2\;dx\leq 0$$
which implies that $E(u(t))$ is decreasing.

Comment: @Pedro: Can we do the other way around starting from amathnerd's eq(1)?  I tried but got stuck too.

Comment: @PatrickWindance When we calculate $\frac{d}{dt}E$, the terms of $(2)$ appear naturally. Thus, I don't think so we can do it from $(1)$

Comment: @Pedro is there some kind of way to solve this exercise using maximum principle?

Comment: @LuizaSilva What exactly do you want to show? Do you want to show that the energy is decreasing by using the maximum principle?