# Strictly decreasing energy function for the PDE $u_t=ku_{xx}-\mu u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

> Prove that energy function $Ε(t)=\int\limits_{0}^{L}u^2(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is strictly decreasing for the problem ($k,\mu>0$):
> $$
> \left \{\begin {array}{lll}
> u_t=ku_{xx}-\mu u &,~ 0<x<L,~t>0\\
> u(x,0)= \phi(x)>0 &, 0<x<L
> \end{array}
> \right.,
> $$
> where $\phi(0)=\phi(L)=0$ and $u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$ for all $t>0$.

*Attempt.* Using integration py parts we get for all $t>0$

$$E'(t) =-2k\int\limits_{0}^{L}u_{x}^2\,\mathrm{d}x- 2\mu \int\limits_{0}^{L}u^2\,\mathrm{d}x\leqslant 0.$$
If for some $t_0>0$ we have $E'(t_0)=0$, then  using continuity of $u$ we derive
$u(x,t_0)=0$ for all $x\in (0,L)$. My question is:

*How does this contradict hypothesis $u(x,0)>0$ for $0<x<L$?*

(note that $u$ does not satisfy the heat equation, in order to attain its minimum of the parabolic boundary).

Comment: I can't get a contradiction, but note that if $E'(t_0) = 0$, then $E(t_0) = 0$, and hence (since $E$ is decreasing) $E(t) = 0$ for all $t > t_0$.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, i reached that point also, using the decreasing property of $E$ (so $u(x,t)=0$ for all $x\in (0,L)$ and $t \geq t_0$). But again, where is a contradiction?

Comment: It's been a long time since I solved the heat equation, so I'm a bit fuzzy on the details. If I remember right, it's a consequence of the fundamental solution that non-zero solutions to the heat equation remain non-zero for all time (and propagate instantaneously). I would like to say something like "If $u=0$ for a time interval, then by reversing time it must have been zero in the past", but I think solutions to the heat equation are unstable under time reversal. So I think it's true, but I can't see an easy argument!

Comment: A time reversal would work, but i have never seen this property on heat equation.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Can you point out in which textbook/paper/article you saw this question? I'd like to read the section or material before responding.

Comment: Doesn't $u e^{\mu t}$ satisfy the heat equation?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, it is from a past exam.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout What was the reference, or standard textbook for the exam in that course?

Comment: Hm, lately the standard reference is  Partial Differential Equations from Strauss. But I think that when the problem was given (3 years ago), there was a Greek textbook as reference (i don't think it would help you).

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Anyway, I will look at Strauss and get back. If it was an exam question, I will snap my fingers off to get it!

Comment: @NikolaosSkout I reached the same conclusion, and I am *very sure* that it is not required. I went through most of the details you probably went through, and I wanted to post an answer, but what I can see is that clearly that condition is not required. It may be required for existence/uniqueness of $u$, though.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Even [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580569/nonlinear-heat-equation-with-decreasing-energy-function?rq=1) you can see there is no dependence on the initial condition $g(x)$ in the argument. I just realize : it is also possible that this exam  question may have more parts to it , and you mention just one part of the exercise : another part may require positivity of $\phi$, maybe some uniqueness or time-reversal statement.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I see. That was indeed the first part. The second part had that same conclusion, with Neumann conditions instead of Dirichlet conditions and the third part was to prove that $E(t) \to 0$ as $t\to +\infty$ (with either the hypothesis of the first or the second part).

Comment: Great! I will try to answer all of them!

Comment: Thank you Teresa. I have solved the third part, the first two are still unsolved (i guess solving the first is enough the get the idea for the second part).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, I didn't ask about the third part ($E(t) \to 0$ as $t\to 0$) since I have done it. Sketch of proof: for Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions, we get $E'(t)=-2k\int_0^Lu_x^2\mathrm{d}x-2\mu E(t)$ and $e^{2\mu t}E(t)$ is decreasing. So $0\leqslant E(t)\leqslant e^{-2\mu t}E(0)$ for all $t$ and conclude.

Comment: Duplicate. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904117/asymptotic-behaviour-of-the-energy-of-the-pde-u-t-ku-xx-mu-u?rq=1).

Comment: It is not duplicate. Please focus on the initial post.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Ok, so you have got that it is decreasing, the $\leq $ sign is there. You are asking, why should there be a $<$ sign? Ok, that will require the initial conditions for a reason! Nice, I should have seen that earlier.

Comment: After Laplace transforming $U(s,x) = \left(\frac{1}{s+\mu}\right)\left(k U_{xx}(s,x)+\phi(x)\right)$